# ASCII code interpretation (assembly)

Tags: ascii, assembly, masm, tasm

First of all, thanks for all the help thus far.

Complete code can be found [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/assembly/threads/117744)

I have trouble understanding these lines. I wrote some comments...

The line, for example, mov es:[si+6], al means move data in al to the memory address marked by si+6 (I think this would be an offset calculation).

Then what is **add si,40** in the loop?

Any helps mean everything to me! Thank you.

```
L0_95:         ; this segment prints ASCII code 0 - 95
mov si,6       ; refers to the string we declared at the beginning
mov cx,4       ; I think this is the height?

C1A:
; this loop adds the name of the column
mov al,string[0]
mov es:[si],al
mov al,string[2]
mov es:[si+6],al
mov al,string[4]
mov es:[si+24],al
mov al,string[6]
mov es:[si+28],al
add si,40           ;;;; what is this line?
loop C1A

mov si,122          ;;;; and these three lines?
mov bx,0
mov cx,4
C1B:push cx  

mov cx,24
add si,40
C1C:push cx
call DEC_CONVERT
add si,2
call HEX_CONVERT
add si,2
call BIN_CONVERT
add si,2
call CHAR_CONVERT
inc bx
add si,126
pop cx
loop C1C
pop cx
sub si,3840
loop C1B

ret

L96_191:
```

Comment: surely you could google or look up the doco yourself?

Comment: Wait, you want us to help you understand somebody else's 16-bit DOS assembly language homework from three years ago? How would we know if it even works?

Comment: hmmm first i appreciate coming here. well... part of learning a computer language is reading someone else's code, isn't it? unlike c++ or java or python, docs aren't very informative IMO. and maybe because i am still a beginner at this point.

Comment: No problem with being a beginner, we're here to help. However, I would suggest starting with some *real* learning materials (search for "x86 tutorial", for example), instead of some undocumented homework code found on some random forum.

Comment: The 8086 (and with it, 16-bit code) hasn't been useful for a while now.  You'd really do better to start out with 32-bit x86 code.  I highly recommend [Iczelion's Win32 tutorials](http://win32assembly.online.fr/); they're a bit old, but almost everything in them still applies.

Comment: this is awesome. i really thanks all the suggestions here !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add si` advances the si register by 40.
`mov si,122` sets the si register to 122, probably the address of some data.  The remaining two instructions should now be self-explanatory.

Comment: urgh. right. i keep forgetting about how to interpret the integers. i really thank you your help, wallyk.